# have set the required property via formula but now there is no option to have a message

Tags: xpages, required

I have set the required property to @IsDocBeingSaved but then there is no option to enter s validation message. How do you make a control required under specific conditions and still have a message when it is required

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the source. Or: check it as required, enter the message, then switch to the computation. The message doesn't get deleted

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I ended up doing is creating a under the validators properties I created a validateRequired and added code to the loaded and disableValidators to make it only active during saving. Works well, just not real obvious. I have used some validators before but not often. Need to keep remembering to go there.